# TFS 2010 and MSBuild variables empty?

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

we developer web pages in PHP and we must use Visual studio 2010 with Team foundation Server 2010.
We try to create simple "build process" on TFS to copy our php files to drop folder.

I am using: DefaultTemplate.xaml
And created my own: simple_zip.proj for MSBuild proces with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="**\*.php"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="CopyFiles">
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination" />
        <Message Text="My Build Complete" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

And this works and copies to the server local path.

The problem is if I try to use any of MSBuild variables it does not work, like

Message Text="My Build Complete - $(BuildDir) - $(TargetDir) - $(BuildProjectFolderPath)>"

My text is displayed but variables are empty (I am looking debug level log files of msbuild process).

Also anything from the following link, simply does not work.
[Customizable Team Foundation Build Targets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337604.aspx)

So my question is, how can I get all path variables (sources dir, binaries dir, drop folder dir, build number and others from build definition/template) to my MSBuild on the TFS server ?

Thank you
Kind regards

Comment: In your previous post you've asked about BuildNumber. You should youself pass all required values through command line in the same way as for BuildNumber

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your project importing any standard targets.  I do a similar thing in one of my project files and it looks a bit like this:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<PropertyGroup>
 <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
 <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
 <DeploymentDir>$(OutDir)\MySubFolder\</DeploymentDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
 <DeploymentContent Include="**\*.ps1" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
 <DevDeploymentImageDir>$(DeploymentDir)Dev\</DevDeploymentImageDir>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" />
<!-- Empty targets for this project since it just copies files from one location to another.-->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild"/>
<Target Name="CreateManifestResourceNames" />
<Target Name="CoreCompile" />
<Target Name="AfterBuild" >
  <MakeDir Directories="$(DeploymentDir)" />
  <MakeDir Directories="$(DevDeploymentImageDir)" />
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(DeploymentContent)" DestinationFolder="$(DevDeploymentImageDir)" />
</Target>
```

Another good thing to try is turning on more verbose MSBuild logging on your TFS machine (like the level 'diag') so you can see MSBuild variables getting set along the way as the build progresses.

Comment: I am using debug level for MSBUild logging, and there are no any variables. Also project you specified is ok, but still my variables ($(DeploymentDir) etc.) are all just simple empty :/

Comment: Also, $(Configuration) , $(Platform) etc are empty in my case, tried to Message Text="My configuration - $(Configuration)" , and these are empty as all other variables. My question is how can i troubleshoot this and get them to populate with values ? :) thank you

Comment: how can $(DeploymentDir) be empty in this example when I've initialized it to <DeploymentDir>$(OutDir)\MySubFolder\</DeploymentDir>  in this case it will at least be \MySubFolder\ when $(OutDir) doesn't exist.

Comment: Is this proj file nested below another one in your build workflow?  i.e. are you calling MSBuild recursively or do you just have a list of proj files in the TFS Build Definition that you are maintaining?

Comment: Finally, one more thing.  You've confirmed that your proj file has the following line in it: <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets" /> 
?  This line imports the std MSBuild common targets and properties.

Comment: Yes i know and i have imported that Common targets and they work. Sorry for misunderstanding DeploymentDir, i mean that $(OutDir) is empty.

Comment: Wou, it seems that $(OutDir) is working and pointing to binaries directory, which is fine.

Comment: But still variable $(BuildNumber) or $(TeamProject) or $(BuildProperties) or ..., are emtpy :/ buildnumber is decided by build template on tfs

Comment: Also,  <Target Name="AfterBuild"> does not work (runs) at all

Comment: Sorry, but you never answered the question" Is this proj file nested below another one in your build workflow? i.e. are you calling MSBuild recursively or do you just have a list of proj files in the TFS Build Definition that you are maintaining?"  I ask because if you are nesting proj files, you are likely calling the MSBuild Task.  If this is so, you'd need to explicitly pass the $(buildnumber) var, etc, to the next level:

Comment: <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectFiles)"
             BuildInParallel="$(BuildInParallel)"
             SkipNonexistentProjects="$(SkipNonexistentProjects)"
             Properties="SkipInvalidConfigurations=$SkipInvalidConfigurations);Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(ProjectPlatform);OutDir=$(OutDir);BuildNumber=$(BuildNumber);RunCodeAnalysis=$(RunCodeAnalysis)"
             Targets="Build"
             />